# How to Send 2 different type of data in 1 socket in java

Tags: java

can somebody help me to send 2 different data type over 1 socket only from android to java server ... i have to send an array and a string together. Its crashing the app

```
   private void Send()
{
    Thread t = new Thread() {

        public void run() {

            try {

                Socket s = new Socket("192.168.0.3", 7000);
                ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

                out.writeObject(array);
                out.flush();
                out.close();

                DataOutput out1 =new DataOutput(s.getOutputStream()); 
                out1.writeUTF(id); 
                out1.flush(); 
                out1.close;
                s.close();

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Message Sent !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Combine them in a new Object with two properties (first value and second value) and send that new Object.

Comment: If you can't combine the array and the string then send a fixed size header first (might be some number) which defines what type of data the rest is expected to be.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the error in your code is, that the Outputstream of your Socket is allready closed. The problem is that, if you close anykind of stream, all underlying streams are also closed. So if you close your ObjectOutputStream, the stream from the socket is closed automatically too.

If I were you, I would create a new class holding all the data you need, and send only an instance of this class.

```
    class TempObject {

        public TempObject(Object[] array, String id) {
            this.array = array;
            this.id = id;
        }

        public Object[] array;
        public String id;
    }

    private void Send() {

        TempObject obj = new TempObject(array, id);
        Socket s = new Socket("192.168.0.3", 7000);
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        out.writeObject(obj);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
```

Comment: actually before the method send i have some function which assign the array ... then will it assign the array if i use the method u have suggest ?

Comment: depends on where your array is defined...If it is defined as a class variable then the array will be okay in your function. But if the array is defined in your function, you must forward it via parameters to the Send function.

Comment: ok understood and on the server side how will i receive/read this object ? How will i be able to loop and differentiate between what am receiving?

Comment: On the server side, you just use a ObjectInputStream, which works basically the same. There you will be able to call the function "readObject" which will give you a object back. This object can simply be casted back into a TempObject instance --> you need your Data Class in both client and server.

Comment: in first trial it is working ... wen i try again its crashing :( 
plz help me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send more then one element use table or collection. If you want to send string and int variable, you can create your own class to store them.